# Alerta Bootstrap solo se muestra una sola vez

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

tengo un detalle con una alerta Bootstrap.

cuando hago un registro muestro una alerta de registro exitoso, el cual solo se muestra y desaparece en cierto tiempo pero cuando vuelvo a realizar otro registro la alerta ya no aparece. en pocas palabras la alerta solo aparece una sola vez.

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
    $("#boton").click(function(){
        
    $("#ok").removeClass("hidden");
          setTimeout(function(){
              $("#ok").fadeOut(3000);
              },3000);
              
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button id='boton'>Registrar</button>

<div id="ok" class="alert alert-success hidden" role="alert">registrado exitosamente! <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con la propiedad `style` de `CSS` y el valor `none` y `block` para ocultar y mostrar el `alert`.

```js
$(window).ready(function () {
  $("#boton").click(function () {
    var x = document.getElementById("ok");
    x.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#ok").fadeOut(3000);
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id='boton'>Registrar</button>

<div id="ok" class="alert alert-success" style="display:none" role="alert">registrado exitosamente! <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Y en el `class` del `div` quita `hidden` y agregar `style="display:none"` para que permanezca oculto y solo al presionar el botón se visualice y oculte en 3 segundos con `setTimeout()`.

Esto permitirá abrirlo y cerrarlo cuantas veces se necesite.

Comment: Muchas Gracias.. si me funciono